# Android Java - SoundPool sounds stop playing for some reason

Tags: java, android, audio, soundpool

Well , I use SoundPool for onClick on ImageView sounds and some of them starts another Activity. Like this :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.main_menue_status:{
button_click.play(button_clickID, 1,1, 0, 0, 1); //this is SoundPoool's play
    Intent intent=new Intent(context,MainMenueActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

other activities has same ImageViews(actually, buttons) to navigate through the app. 
And all the time I use finish(); to prevent creating millions of copies of activities. 
So after about 30 SoundPool's plays sound stops playing at all.

My guess is that's because I finish() Activity before sound complete it's playback so somehow system stop playing any SoundPool at all.

Any advice?

UPD : Log :

```
12-01 19:04:49.797: E/AudioTrack(19981): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
12-01 19:04:49.797: E/SoundPool(19981): Error creating AudioTrack
```

Comment: How and when are you loading your sound resources? I believe "status: -12" is an Out of Memory error. I would think that either you're loading sounds that are way too big, or you're hitting the device cap on loaded audio tracks, which is technically 32, but usually less.

Comment: every SoundPool has maximum of 3 playbacks (1st parameter), so I got 2-3 SoundPool objects in every Activity. When I leave Activity - I use finish(), so as I assume - memory should be freed.

Comment: That might not be the case. finish() is not a guarantee that the Activity will be immediately finished. I would try, instead, loading your sound resources in onResume(), and unloading in onPause().

Comment: Btw, the first parameter in SoundPool's constructor is the max number of _simultaneous_ streams, not max number of loadable resources.

Comment: I know about streams, just used wrong term. how can I unload them?

Comment: SoundPool.unLoad(sound_id)

Comment: together with .release() it made the trick. You can make an answer and I'll accept it if you wish

Comment: Excellent! Sorry, I should've had you release, too. As long as you're re-instantiating the SoundPool, too, in onResume(), it should be cool. Thanks, I will make it an answer.  Need the SO street cred!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "status: -12", I believe, is an Out of Memory error. Also, calling `finish()` in an Activity is not a guarantee that the Activity will immediately finish and release resources.

Since you have several Activities and several SoundPools, I would recommend creating the SoundPool and loading your sound resources in the Activity's `onResume()` method, and then unloading the resources and releasing the SoundPool in the onPause() method.